# What does a certain character say when you talk to him for the "Bearer of Bad News" quest?

Tags: borderlands-2

SPOILERS!  This quest is right after a **major** story event near what seems to be the end of the game, so please don't read the rest of the question or any answers if you'd like to remain in the dark.  I'll use spoiler tags, but I can't vouch for answers :)

Okay, so...

> After Roland is killed by Jack, Mordecai gives an optional quest to tell other major characters in Sanctuary that Roland is dead.  I went and talked to all the characters, however I think it glitched when I talked to Brick because he only repeated the speech he was giving Mordecai when I first came back to Sanctuary (about Jack killing his dog).

What is he supposed to say here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC he gives one of his "bandit-style" (i.e passionate, with lots of yelling) speeches that goes something like:

> We didn't see eye-to-eye on everything, but Roland was my friend, so make Jack pay for this!

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  It was gonna take me *forever* to get another character to the same point.

Comment: Glad I could help :)